# how to close gracefully a kivy app on Android?

Tags: android, python, python-2.7, kivy

I have a kivy app with this inside :

```
Button:
    text: "Close"
    on_release: app.stop()
```

This works well. But unfortunately, when the app is executed on Android, the app stops but not gracefully as an Android dialog box opens up saying that the app has been closed. And this is not the expected behavior of a normal ending.

So my question : how to close gracefully a kivy app on Android in order to not see this annoying dialog box?

Below is the output of logcat :

```
I/python  ( 4960): ANSWERS (on_stop in App) =  None
I/python  ( 4960): screen names =  ['welcome']
I/python  ( 4960): answers have been saved on disk
I/python  ( 4960): closing the SQL connection...
I/python  ( 4960): now returning True
I/python  ( 4960): [INFO   ] [Base        ] Leaving application in progress...
I/python  ( 4960): ANSWERS (on_stop in App) =  None
I/python  ( 4960): screen names =  ['welcome']
I/python  ( 4960): answers have been saved on disk
I/python  ( 4960): closing the SQL connection...
I/python  ( 4960): now returning True
I/python  ( 4960): Python for android ended.
```

As you can see, the App.on_stop() method seems to have been called twice.

Thanks for your ideas.

Answer (score 1):

Have you overridden `on_stop()` method of your app? Try this.

```
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.app import App


Builder.load_string("""
<MyWidget>:
    BoxLayout:
        Button:
            text: "Close"
            on_release: app.stop()
""")


class MyWidget(BoxLayout):
    pass


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyWidget()

    def on_stop(self):
        return True

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

Comment: Thanks @Juggernaut but unfortunately it doesn't change anything. I'm still getting the dialogbox.

Comment: It's ok on API 19 on my htc desire 525

Comment: Thanks @Juggernaut. I'm using API 19 as well. I think my problem may be due to the fact that I do some tasks in the on_stop method, like writing into a database. Well I'm not sure ; it's just an idea. What version of python do you use? I'm using python2.7.

Comment: same python version here. Did you take time to look at adb logcat ?

Comment: Nothing special appear in the logcat, except that it seems that the on_stop method is called twice! I will edit my question to add the output of logcat.